# How can I link to a public google profile through an iFrame?

Tags: html, iframe, same-origin-policy

As an example the following does not work

```
<iframe src="https://plus.google.com/110145602671775846965/about?hl=en" />
```

Even though I can visit the page directly.  Is there any way of getting around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is not. Like most Google applications, Google Plus uses the X-Frame-Options to block framing of pages on their site. This is a browser security mechanism; as such, there is no way to disable it.